# Will I break debian etch if I install python-support 0.7.1 to it?

Tags: debian, python, upgrade

I tried to install `s3cmd` into my Debian `etch`, but the following error message comes up:

```
root@NAS-01G:~/src$ sudo apt-get install s3cmd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Since you only requested a single operation it is extremely likely that
the package is simply not installable and a bug report against
that package should be filed.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  s3cmd: Depends: python-support (>= 0.7.1) but 0.5.6 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I am thinking of upgrading to `python-support 0.7.1`; will this break my system?

Comment: It is absolutely fine to have many python versions on the same system. Just don't remove any existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

First, Debian etch is really old (originally released Apr 8th 2007). I suggest you upgrade if possible. At this point even security updated of etch are [not longer supported](http://www.debian.org/News/2010/20100121).

In any case, since s3cmd is not in etch, you must be trying to install a more recent version. One option is to try to backport it to etch, by building the package on etch. If a more recently version of python-support is really required, then you can try building python-support on etch first. Installing a more recent version of python-support may or may not work, but will probably not break anything. However, if you want to play it safe, I suggest you test in a virtual machine first. I'd probably try these options in the order suggested.